# Generic display xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

Is there a way that can enable me to display multi items in a single row without hardcoding the xaml eg I have a class that has 8 fields, At run time, one or more fields will not be null. So meaning I don't know at developer time which fields will be null and not null. So only not null values will be displayed, and all the nulls will be hidden Instead of hardcoding the interface (xaml) I'm looking for a generic way of displaying values.. I have a working solution but there is a lot of hard coding.. WinRT

eg my class can be like this

[Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po2lw.png)

And xaml is designed in such a way that I set the visibility of the language from the code. If the user select to display English and Chinese, the visibility of the Chinese in language class is set to true, the interface will display in each row a phrase in Chinese and English depending on the user's choice

Comment: There are lots of ways to address this question. You need to narrow the problem _considerably_. Templating is the way to deal with "not hardcoding the XAML". You can create a template that has a style with a trigger that hides an item if the value is null. Please try _something_. Then if you have trouble, post a new question that includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you tried, and a clear precise explanation of what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you want to show. Don't worry, you don't need to provide a working project or a history of your Google searches to ask a question on StackOverflow. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your form like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding FirstName, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedWhenNullConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="First Name:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding LastName, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedWhenNullConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="Last Name:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

You can write the converter CollapsedWhenNullConverter to return Collapsed when the value is null and Visible when the value is not null. Like this:

```
class CollapsedWhenNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value == null) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That will hide the null fields for you, if that's really what you want. There's nothing to stop you from creating an equivalent, custom `VisibleWhenTrue` converter, too. It's up to your data, but that should get you started to make your display dynamic.